# Restrict google autocomplete to one country when using no libraries

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am making the autocomplete API request like this.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json&key=mykey&input=ko

This is working fine. But how can we restrict the results to one country?

I tried to pass in country restriction using components as mentioned in [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete) like below.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json&key=mykey&input=ko&components=country:fr . But it's still returning all countries. Could someone tell me the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Components are available for the Place Autocomplete method (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete) but not for the Query Autocomplete method (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/query).

The parameter you are providing is getting ignored.